# Why MVC is not binding byte array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I remember properly, my application was binding successfully everything. But now it doesn't, and I don't know, it never did or I broke something.

Here is a controller:

```
    public void SaveToDataBase(EnhancedXml enhancedXml)
    {

    }
```

where `EnhancedXml` is very simple:

```
public class EnhancedXml
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public byte[] AdvancedSignature { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my HttpRequest:

```
POST http://localhost:35921/SaveToDb HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:35921/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 38027
Host: localhost:35921
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"enhancedXml":{"Content":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Student xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Name>Alex</Name><LastName>B</LastName><DateOfBirth>1993-05-18T00:00:00</DateOfBirth></Student>","AdvancedSignature":[60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,101,110,99]}}
```

When `Content` property is binding fine, `AdvancedSignature` doesn't at all.
Can it be fixed in some way except `create a string property and marshall an array on your own"?

Comment: `AdvancedSignature`  should not be the type `byte[]`?

Comment: The JSON clearly shows an array of numbers (bytes in your case). You need to have that mapped to an array or List as well. You mentioned bytes so change it to `List<byte>` or byte[] instead of string.

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho it should, but I get `null` instead.

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho ahh, sorry, it was a wrong code. Sure i have `byte[]` there, I just was playing with code to make it work, and it's one of alternatives. Sorry again, I mislead everyone.

Comment: Have you tried to send the JSON this way: `{"Content":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Student xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Name>Alex</Name><LastName>B</LastName><DateOfBirth>1993-05-18T00:00:00</DateOfBirth></Student>","AdvancedSignature":[60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,101,110,99]}`? Without the `{"enhancedXml":`...

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho same result, `Content` is filled while byte array is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype for your Advanced Signature is wrong. It should be a list of integers.

```
public class EnhancedXml
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<int> AdvancedSignature { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, very strange... Array is not working for unknown reason, when List is ok.